# How to store sqlite database directly on sdcard with Android 28 (Pie)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the following code:
https://github.com/devendrachavan/SQLiteExample

DatabaseHelperClass.java included with the code uses:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
```

I would like to modify the current constructor allowing the sqlite database be stored on my sdcard or another directory on the device that can be accessed from file explore without rooting.

```
//Constructor included in DatabaseHelperClass.java
public DatabaseHelperClass (Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

I have tried this database helper function and didn't get results:
https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=d70ad5f8-153a-48a6-951b-6be5ac3a7589

I have tried to put a hard path before DATABASE_NAME and didn't get results

My AndroidManifest.xml currently contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Code will compile however app will close when database is accessed. I'm not certain how to get things working using Android OS 28 Pie.

Using the following constructor:

public DatabaseHelperClass (Context context) {
super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

gets the following error:

Logcat(debug):

```
2021-11-03 04:02:58.992 6200-6200/com.example.sqliteexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sqliteexample, PID: 6200
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:160)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:150)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:101)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:78)
        at com.example.sqliteexample.DatabaseHelperClass.<init>(DatabaseHelperClass.java:59)
        at com.example.sqliteexample.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14210)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7323)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:849)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27895)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7266)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
2021-11-03 04:02:59.038 6200-6200/com.example.sqliteexample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6200 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `have tried this database helper function and didn't get results:` What went wrong?

Comment: Code will compile however app will close when database is accessed.

Comment: I wish I had a solution. I'd like to modify the current constructor for the code I'm using allowing the sqlite database to be stored on my sdcard or another directory on the device that can be accessed from file explore without rooting.

Comment: You said that before. Why repeat? And isnt it more urgent to solve the crash?

Comment: Logcat (debug) shows:
2021-11-03 04:02:58.992 6200-6200/com.example.sqliteexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sqliteexample, PID: 6200
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
2021-11-03 04:02:59.038 6200-6200/com.example.sqliteexample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6200 SIG: 9

Comment: Please post logcat lines in your post. In a code block so they are readable. Remove that comment.